# Domain Forwarding - Mobile view doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, mobile, dns, themes

I have redirected domain to a website, it's all working perfectly except mobile view.

Default Android browser and safari iPhone browser doesn't display page corectly it just make it smaller to fit on a screen, anyother mobile phone browsers are displaying page correctly. What can cause the issue?

I am using godaddy hosting and domains and I am doing domain forwarding with masking 301 (Permanent).

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of presenting sites according to the device used, creating a whole website to mobile devices, putting it on a specific subdomain or making responsive site (which from what I saw is what you're trying to do).

To have a satisfactory performance by creating responsive websites I advise the use of bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/